# BASH - Simple script with rm command doesn't work

Tags: bash

I have made this simple script:

```
#/bin/bash
DATE=$(date +"%d_%m_%Y-%H:%M:%S")
tar -czvf /kopie/bin-$DATE.tar /bin
DATE=$(date --date="2 hours ago" +"%d-%m-%Y_%H")
rm -f /kopie/bin-$DATE*.tar
```

I have problem with the last line of the script. rm command doesn't work, it doesn't delete file. The "2 hours ago" date works great, so it's not problem with this.

Comment: Remove the `-f` and you'll get an error message. What does it say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to specify the file name in two different ways:

```
DATE=$(date --date="2 hours ago" +"%d-%m-%Y_%H")
```

Above, there is e.g. a _ between year and hour.

But the date you generated had a different format:

```
DATE=$(date +"%d_%m_%Y-%H:%M:%S")
```

However this still would not solve the inherent problem of getting "a date **more or less** two hours ago", because it takes a single second to go from 13:00:00 to 12:59:59, which does not match a "2017-11-20_13*" pattern anyway.

I'd look into using `find`:

```
 find . -name "*.tar"  -maxdepth 0 -cmin +120 -delete
```

should kill all *.tar files in the current directory older than two hours (use +119 to have a one minute grace time). Also, you can omit `-delete` when testing whether this approach works.

Comment: What a stupid mistake. Thank you for help :)

Comment: I don't remember exactly how many times *I* made this same mistake, but I'm fairly certain it is pretty significant. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with the expansion of the `$DATE` variable in the last line. To test this, you can simply add an `echo` in front of the `rm` command and run the script, or you can try to prevent the issue by using `${DATE}` instead of just `$DATE` in the `rm` command.

The problem could also be that you're trying to delete a filename that doesn't exist, since you appear to have two different date output formats specified, and I'm assuming the date formats are supposed to match between the creation of the tar file and the deletion two hours later.